# How to read a very large csv file (MORE THAN 30GB) in batches using Java

Tags: java

Header says it all. The file roughly contains a few months worth of data. I think that it is unwise to go and read the whole thing and store it into memory so I heard that by doing so in batches it would be much much faster. But I've never tried before and am unsure how to start.

The file contains a few months worth of data and contains dates in unix time, my task is to count the lines and segregate them into different months. Then narrow to the month with the most number of records and from that month narrow further to find the day with most number of records and narrow even further down to the hour.

Any ideas how to do so?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the [help] and read [ask].  You are expected to make an effort to solve the problem and when you run into something you don't understand, THEN ask a specific question.   StackOverflow is not for tutorials, discussions, or having other people write code for you. The approach you should take is to process the file one line at a time and extract/aggregate only the information you need.  If all you need to do is _identify_ the month/day/hour with the most records, this can be done with a Map data structure.

Comment: If you only need to query a few times, try JimGarrison's or george-poliovei's  method. If you need to query many times, try sort it first (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read the file line by line , and using regex extract those lines that match certain pattern in different files

Answer (score 0):

Split your file in manageable pieces and perform sort and merge sorting (External sorting).

Also, change your logger to split records in smaller pieces. For instance, close previous log and open a new one every day or hour. Consider using an SQL database if you expect to analyze logs frequently.